# ajax request header has content-type application/json on dev server but text/html on production

Tags: php, ajax, json, apache, drupal

Running a Drupal website on a LAMP stack. Using the [Advanced Poll module](https://drupal.org/project/advpoll), where votes and canceled votes are processed via ajax.

On my dev server this works just fine; on my production server, I get HTTP 500 error ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXtBh.png)).

Looking at console headers output, I can see that the request is being sent by POST with content-type application/json on my dev server, but on my production server with content-type text/html and gzip content-encoding.

What the hell? Other ajax requests from other modules are working just fine on both servers...

Compare these two screenshots:

DEV SERVER

[image]

PRODUCTION SERVER

[image]

Comment: It is just mean that your application have some problem/issue on production server. So application send default response type (text/html). You need to check problems through web server logs or any other debug. Remeber all server type error like 404, 500 or similar response type will be text/html until you override this through application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just mean that your application have some problem/issue on production server. So application send default response type (text/html). You need to check problems through web server logs or any other debug. Remeber all server type error like 404, 500 or similar response type will be text/html until you override this through application

Comment: Well... I feel stupid. Thanks for the quick answer. Now I just have to figure out what the actual problem is :(